# How to add custom parameter while sending http servlet response

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to set custom parameter in resonse while sending from filter,usually from controllers we are sending customized json format like

Response format from controller

```
                     {
                      "data": {

                         },
                        “message”:”Changes saved”,
                        “status”:200,
                        “timestamp”:1222234,
                        “isSuccess”:true

}
```

Response sending from Controller

```
return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(configProp.getProperty("success"), HttpStatus.OK, true,
                userService.deleteAccount(loggedInUser));
```

Response Handler

```
public final class ResponseHandler implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ResponseHandler(){};

    public static Map<String, Object> generateResponse(String message,
            HttpStatus status, boolean isSuccess,Object responseObj) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(5);
        try {
            map.put(Constant.MESSAGE, message);
            map.put(Constant.STATUS, status.value());
            map.put(Constant.IS_SUCCESS, isSuccess);
            map.put(Constant.DATA, responseObj);
            map.put(Constant.TIME_STAMP, new Date());
            return map;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            map.clear();
            map.put(message, e.getMessage());
            map.put("status", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            map.put("timestamp", new Date());           
            return map;
        }
    }
}
```

In filters,we checks authorization of user,send response by using **HttpServletResponse** like

Filter Response

```
{
  "timestamp": 1461064846379,
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Invalid token",
  "path": "/api/v1/my/favourite/123103"
}
```

My Authentication Filter

```
if(token != null){
                processTokenAuthentication(token);
            }else{
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid token");
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException internalAuthenticationServiceException) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            logger.error("Internal authentication service exception", internalAuthenticationServiceException);
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } catch (AuthenticationException authenticationException) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authenticationException.getMessage());
        } catch (org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ((HttpServletResponse)response).setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            logger.error("your account is not enabled please contact your admin");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.error(jsonException.getLocalizedMessage());
            jsonException.printStackTrace();
             httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, jsonException.getMessage());
        }
```

But i am getting different format of json response from filters. Can i customized **HttpServletResponse** for consistency ?